# how can I create a key in cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm still learning to use cytoscape. I have created a compound-target-cancer network and would like to add a key at the bottom, explaining what the different colors of the nodes mean. For example the pink proteins represent cancer-related proteins, the blue proteins represent non-cancer related proteins and the green nodes are my compounds.
Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an app under development to provide an easy way to do that. but it probably won't be available until Cytoscape 3.7.  In the meantime, you can go to the Style tab, then you'll see a menu tab (four parallel lines), click on that and you'll see a "Create Legend..." option.  That will bring up a legend that can be saved as a PNG and add back into your network using a post-processing program.

-- scooter